# "Visual" search/filter builder for PHP

Tags: php, content-filtering

Take a look at this search builder (above the table): https://editor.datatables.net/examples/extensions/searchBuilderPreDefined.html

Does anything like that exist for PHP?

I'm looking for a proper "filtering" framework that allows a non-coder to build many such sets of rules so I can save them and later use them to filter (exclude/include) "massive" arrays containing product data coming from a db.

I know I can copy the ui, generate the rules as php code and execute them with eval() server-side but I'm looking for something that relies on functions, etc.

edit: If you use the ui to build a "query" like in this image

[image: conditions]

the following will be generated

```
searchBuilder[criteria][0][criteria][0][condition]: =
searchBuilder[criteria][0][criteria][0][origData]: office
searchBuilder[criteria][0][criteria][0][value1]: Tokyo
searchBuilder[criteria][0][criteria][1][condition]: contains
searchBuilder[criteria][0][criteria][1][origData]: first_name
searchBuilder[criteria][0][criteria][1][value1]: a
searchBuilder[criteria][0][logic]: AND
searchBuilder[criteria][1][condition]: contains
searchBuilder[criteria][1][origData]: last_name
searchBuilder[criteria][1][value1]: a
searchBuilder[logic]: AND
```

that will then be sent to the backend to generate this part of the sql query

```
WHERE ((`office` = 'Tokyo' AND  `first_name` LIKE '%a%') AND  `last_name` LIKE '%a%')
```

that then gets executed and returns the matching db data to the frontend.

I want a php script that takes the searchBuilder[...] stuff and uses them to filter an array (by unsetting/dropping non-matching values, for example).

But, I don't want to create an `if (($arr['office'] === 'Tokyo' &&.....`  that will be passed to `eval()`, I want proper php functions that use the searchBuilder[...] to filter an array that contains all the db data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It would be easier for others to answer your question, if you were to summarise the requirements instead of posting a link.

Comment: @RohitGupta The link is the summary, but I have added a more detailed example.

Comment: Great, and I have upvoted it.